# Get password safely from HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to get a password from an input form in a safe manner. Originally I was using $_POST[] but I would like a safer method that is reasonably simple and effective.

GetElementById does not seem like a good solution for this but if you think otherwise can you please let me know as I'd like to use it elsewhere if it is.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" >
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do it on the client or server? `$_POST` is the way to get it on the server, `document.getElementById()` is the way to do it in Javascript in the browser.

Comment: So are you looking for a `PHP` solution or `JavaScript`?

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE PHP solution if possible.

Comment: Then receive the answer from [Chris](http://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris)

Comment: @user3245390 Your problem is not how you retrieve something in PHP, your problem is how does it get securely from the client to the server - and the only answer to this question is - use HTTPS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with getting a password from [`$_POST`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). That is how you access [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) data in PHP. HTTP POST is how login forms work on pretty much every website out there, including your bank's.

But you *must* do it over an encrypted connection (that is, one that uses TLS). That is the *only* way to be secure.

Comment: Note: SSL is outdated and insecure. It's couraged to only use TLS.

Comment: An encrypted connection is a bit beyond most sensible small businesses and that is the level of security I'm aiming for. Surely there must be another solution that at least involves POST itself? Setting up proper encryption is most likely beyond my time constraints.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, isn't SSL version 3 still considered secure? If you can find a reference that shows otherwise I'll happily update my answer.

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/10/14/the-poodle-attack-and-the-end-of-ssl-3-0/

Comment: @user3245390, I'm not sure what you mean. `$_POST` _is_ "POST itself" as far as PHP is concerned. That's the mechanism for accessing POST data in PHP. And there is _no way_ to do this without encryption, full stop. But the good news is that encryption is easier than ever thanks to services like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: That'll do, @CharlotteDunois. Thanks! Updating now.

Comment: @user3245390 It's easy as pie to setup HTTPS, also you can get free certificates from Let's Encrypt and StartSSL. All my websites are only using HTTPS and I'm just a private person, I have no business. So saying it's "beyond most sensible" is just an excuse.

Comment: @Chris Ah damn. I'll check out that link thanks. Quick question, so if I just use POST as is without encryption would I be liable under EU law? I think under EU law I have to take reasonable security measures, it seems maybe I was going overkill?

Comment: @user3245390, I have no idea what EU law says about this. I'm not a lawyer, and I live in Canada. If that is a concern I encourage you to talk to a lawyer directly. But in my opinion this is something you should be doing as a matter of professionalism, regardless of liability. As Charlotte has said it isn't difficult or expensive to set up HTTPS these days.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I have no prior knowledge about encryption, so please excuse my knee jerk reaction when I heard the word encryption and thought I do not have the time to implement such a seemingly big component. If it is as you say I will gladly make the time for it when possible. Please note how I said "Most likely" in my previous comment, I left room for speculation as I was leaving room for elaboration on constraints like time/difficulty; I was not making the claim that I will not do it - I said most likely. When I said sensible I meant businesses that comply with the law.

Comment: @user3245390 There are several tutorials online and google can link you to them. E.g. the term `how to setup HTTP on nginx` links you to this https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm. The same can be done with Apache (if you have Apache), IIS and Lighttpd. For Apache there is even a module from Let's Encrypt to automate the whole certificate process.